# Finding a base for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have this question that I'm not sure of. There is a linear subspace :

$$
V=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2x-y+z&x-2y-2z\\
x+y-z&3x+y+2z
\end{array}\right) :\ x,y,z\in{\Bbb{R}}\}.
$$

I can easily prove that this is a linear subspace but im stuck at finding the base because i can't really rank it.
thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try to write the matrix as a linear combination of some matrices by splitting the terms in x,y and z... Then try to prove that those matrices are linearly independent.

Comment: So i took your hint and actually ranked these: 2 1 1 3 |     -1 -2 1 1 |    1 -2 1 2. and got an answer, hope that's the one. thank you very much

Comment: A minus sign is missing in the last one..